# Ovewrite files option robocopy

Tags: batch-file

I want to automate some copying through a batch file so I am using `robocopy` but I want to make sure I am doing it right. I mean exactly like if I copy-pasted these folders in file explorer the normal way.

Here is the command I am using (correct it if something is missing or wrong):

```bat
robocopy C:\foldernamedHI F:\foldernamedHI /copyall /e
```

Does this command overwrite existing files?

Comment: I don't want to come across rude, but you're only copying stuff, just create a test source and a test destination a try the command. It would be much better and quicker than creating an account, posting a question at the weekend and waiting for an answer. If it doesn't work as you expected, make sure you've read the output of `RoboCopy /?` and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did try this but it doesn't overwrite and i am quite noobie. I am still searching on google and trying to figure it out but I though why don't I get some help from here if I didn't come across something useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't, you have to use `/IS` to overwrite existing files with the same name.

See: https://superuser.com/questions/1114377/does-robocopy-skip-copying-existing-files-by-default

Comment: that was it. Thank you.

Comment: IMHO this answer is not good (although is correct). The next time that the OP have a simple question about a command, he/she will _not_ read the 'help' screen about the command nor do a simple test. The OP will post a question here instead and wait that some people like you do his/her job... **`:(`**